# TFS 2010 no exe files copied after successful build

Tags: build-automation, exe

I am having a TFS 2010 installation along with Visual Studio 2010 (also installed in the server), I created a build definition for a C# project. The Build ends up being successful but I have no .exe files in my drop folder, I can find dlls however,

Has anyone experienced the same issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, that was exactly the problem, one of the 3 projects was set to "x86" instead of "AnyCPU", I noticed after organizing the binaries folders (as by default TFS puts everything in the same folder so it can be difficult to see) using the post:http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build/.

The problem is now solved. Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Imen, if it has worked you should mark one of the answers as the accepted answer (possibly James Reed's one).

Answer (score 6):

This could be a problem with your configurations to build.

In solution Explorer right click on the solution and select "Configuration Manager". This will bring up a list of all of the projects in the solution. The project that creates the "EXE" is probably set to "x86" and the project(s) that create "DLL(s)" are probably set to "AnyCPU".

You should have a "Platform" for each of these, plus a "Platform" for "Mixed Platforms" which will build all of the projects.

Now check in your Build Definition. Look in the process Tab and look at the "Items to Build" setting, make sure that you're building "Release|Mixed Platforms". If you're getting just the dll's in your build output I suspect that your build is set to "Release|AnyCPU"

Comment: Dear all,Thanks for your replies, that was exactly the problem the project was set to "x86" instead of "AnyCPU", I noticed after organizing the bianries folders (as by default TFS puts ervything in the same folder so it can be difficult to see) using the post:

Answer (score 1):

The whole flow of the TFS-Build can be observed if you queue a new build & set `Verbosity = diagnostic`
Once the build ends, open it up and select "View Log".
A `BinariesDirectory` gets its value within `Initialize Binaries Directory`.
Another variable named `OutputDirectory` gets its value  within `Initialize OutputDirectory`, on something that bases on `BinariesDirectory`.
MSBuild drops the outcome into this `OutputDirectory`. 
Finally, within `Copy Files to Drop Location` everything under `BinariesDirectory` gets copied to the drop location.
The activity that does this is `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CopyDirectory`which doesn't focus on any extension - it simply copies the whole directory.

In order to experience what you are reporting, you might be using a non-default build process template XAML, or your MSBuild arguments are somehow altered, or *exe-csproj have a hardcoded output path.
In any case, if you trace the build log as described above, you should be able to find the culprit. 
Good luck!